# How to display Splash Screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display splash screen in android app. But I want to execute `onCreate()` method of MainActivity behind the splash screen. because i am doing huge work in this method. Anyone can tel me how to do that.

Comment: Follow this article to implement splash screen in your app. [Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to do some work in background while user is shown some splash screen, right ? What you need is an Async Task or a Loader kind of thing.

Step 1: Display the splash screen.
Step 2: Start an Async task and do all your heavy processing in the doInBackground method of Async Task
Step 3: Update the UI using the onPostExecute method of Async Task. In this method, first close the timer to splash screen. Then send the intent to start another screen with the data of the heavy processed result of Async task. Display it on UI thread.

Only Showing Splash screen is very simple. This code creates a splash screen of 3 seconds and then sends an Intent to another activity.

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        CountDownTimer cdt1 = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

            Boolean checkInternetConnection = false;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

          //Send Intent here
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                         anotherActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

PS- Dont forget to make the activity with this code as launcher activity  from manifest file.

Comment: This will return to splash screen when you press back button.

Comment: You can simply override onBackPressed() inside the main activity which was opened by splash screen and this will not come: simply give your custom behavior to whatever you want to do. The answer poster is just guiding the OP in the answer and not making his/her whole app.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for Splash Screen...

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

//Further Needed Declarations

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        /**
         * Showing splashscreen while making network calls to download necessary
         * data before launching the app Will use AsyncTask to make http call
         */
        new PrefetchData().execute(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same way you wanted it.

create file in drawable

```
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Press home button to minimize your app. Then run app again from system launcher - new app instance will start, because you have destroyed its launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your onCreate Method

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // going to next activity
                    Intent i=new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            },time);
```

And initialize your time value in milliseconds as yo want...

```
private  static int time=5000;
```

for more detail download full code from this link...

https://github.com/Mr-Perfectt/Splash-Screen